# compiling on Windows and Linux

Tags: c, linux, visual-studio-2008

I am just looking for some guidelines, as this might seem like a very open question.

I have a project that has been compiled using Visual Studio 2008 sp1. I have to compile so it will run linux using gcc 4.4.1 C99.

It is a demo application that I didn't write myself.

The source code is written so it can be cross-platform (linux, windows), so the code will compile and run on linux. However, has it has been developed using VS, I don't have any makefile to use.

I could write a make file. But I am not sure about the dependences as there are about 20 files all together (*.c and *.h).

I am just wondering how can I write a makefile from a visual studio project? Is there any settings I can use?  and what depends on what? Anything else?

Many thanks for any suggestions,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `makedepend` utility will scan the C files you give it, using C preprocessing rules to determine their dependencies and output them to a Makefile.

This should do most of what you want.

Answer (score 3):

One tool that you can use is CMake. CMake can generate a VS.net solution file, and it can generate a Unix makefile. This way is not easy, nor is it the without its bumps in the road. (Especially when the build sequence gets complex)

Answer (score 1):

Start with a very simple Makefile:

```
theapp: *.c *.h Makefile
    gcc *.c -o theapp
```

Those two lines will get you 90% of the way there (and, in a lot of cases, 100% of the way).

Now you can make and run your app in Unix simply with:

```
$ make && ./theapp
```

I *don't* recommend that you use those complex Makefile generators like automake *unless* you plan on releasing this stuff to the world.

For private projects, keep your makefiles simple and clean.

Comment: This just handles the Unix make. Having a cross platform project, one might want to use a tool to generate the appropriate make file per platform.

Comment: The demo application will only be run on a linux platform. So I am only worried about getting it to run on linux.

Comment: Having makefiles that are simple and clean is equally worthwhile when releasing to the world, too.

Comment: Trust me, a hand-written simple Makefile is 1.618 billion times better than those autogen'd ones - you just have no idea what they're doing and customizing them could take hours of reading documentation. GCC is not a complicated program, write your own command line.

Comment: Makefiles should not explicitly indicate how to compile a file; simply stating that a ".o" file depends on a ".cpp" or ".c" file is sufficient for Make to know to invoke gcc, and is more portable.